# Blocking GET requests in Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

So I have a PHP script that I myself have not designed but has a known security flaw. There's an admin panel where the admin can change various profile settings for every user, including their email address. The security flaw is such that anyone who knows the correct URL can change the email address of any registered user, including the admin, so long as they know the corresponding user's ID, by simply calculating the MD5 hash of the new email address they want to change to and issuing a GET request, without ever having to login as an admin. For example, entering the following URL into your browser:

admin.php?userid=1&md5hash=c59152a77c0bc073fe6f2a3141b99010&email=blah@blah.com

Would successfully update the email address of user with ID of "1" to blah@blah.com.

Now from what research I've done so far it appears that ditching MD5 hashes for a slight more proprietary/secure form of encryption would be the best/most secure way of going about this. But while I feel I have a fairly good understanding of PHP and have written a few basic scripts myself, since I haven't designed the particular script in question I'm not sure if this would actually be possible and/or plausible. Also, people do still use MD5 hashes in practice so there must exist another equally feasible way to protect aganist such exploits which led me to looking in to Apache's mod_rewrite module to block specific types of GET requests:

[redacted for irrelevance because of max link limit of 2 for new users]

So my questions would be:

1) Disregarding whether or not it would actually be feasible, would changing the PHP script to using some other form of encryption besides MD5 hashes be the BEST possible way to go about this? Or is there some simple function that I can add to the PHP script itself to protect from this kind of exploit?

2) If I went the route of using Apache's mod_rewrite as describe in the above URL, what would be the best method (out of THE_REQUEST, HTTP_REFERER, HTTP_COOKIE, REQUEST_URI, HTTP_USER_AGENT, QUERY_STRING, and/or REMOTE_ADDR, where REQUEST_METHOD is "GET")? Or is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do this way?

3) Someone had also suggested it may be possible to do what I am trying to do via a .htaccess file? Is this possible and would this method be anymore more or less secure than the other 2 mentioned?

The only thing to take into consideration is that via whichever method I end up using, obviously the server would have to still be able to issue the request for when the admin wants to legitimately change a user's email address. I just need to update it so that the general public cannot change a user's email address by simply typing the correct URL into their browser, given they know the correct user ID. Thanks in advance.

**---> EDIT: Sorry I was neglecting to name the particular script because it is a publicly available one and I wasn't sure if this particular exploit was a known one but turns out it is, so I guess there's no harm in posting it here. The script is TorrentTrade (v2.08)- you can download the entire script at SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/torrenttrader/).**

I've also copied and pasted the entirety of account-ce.php:

```
<?php
//
//  TorrentTrader v2.x
//      $LastChangedDate: 2012-09-28 20:35:06 +0100 (Fri, 28 Sep 2012) $
//      $LastChangedBy: torrenttrader $
//
//      http://www.torrenttrader.org
//

require_once("backend/functions.php");
dbconn();

$id = (int) $_GET["id"];
$md5 = $_GET["secret"];
$email = $_GET["email"];

if (!$id || !$md5 || !$email)
    show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("MISSING_FORM_DATA"), 1);

$res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT `editsecret` FROM `users` WHERE `enabled` = 'yes' AND `status` = 'confirmed' AND `editsecret` != '' AND `id` = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

if (!$row)
    show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("NOTHING_FOUND"), 1);

$sec = $row["editsecret"];

if ($md5 != md5($sec . $email . $sec))
    show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("NOTHING_FOUND"), 1);

SQL_Query_exec("UPDATE `users` SET `editsecret` = '', `email` = ".sqlesc($email)." WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `editsecret` = " . sqlesc($row["editsecret"]));

header("Refresh: 0; url=account.php");
header("Location: account.php");

?>
```

**account-ce.php** is the .php file referenced in following list of several known exploits (the first exploit is the only one i'm looking at right now):

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/21396/

I figured rather than sit around and wait for TorrentTrader to release a new update I would try and be proactive and fix some of the exploits myself.

Comment: The best method is just to fix the script and detect whether the caller is authorized to call the script in the first place

Comment: `without ever having to login as an admin` Why? Shouldn't admin.php check if they're an admin just like any other page?

Comment: You should be using some kind of session. So if the user is logged in and is an Admin, or the info belongs to the logged in user who's accessing it, the update can be done. That's a common way of authorizing/managing permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include in a session handler. I would like to assume that a user is required to login before being allowed to access any admin page, and that some sort of login credential or user id is saved to a session variable. To implement that you would need to have a script like this included on every page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    $redirect_url='login.php';
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        $redirect_url.='?target='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
    header('Location: '.$redirect_url);
}
?>
```

$_SESSION['uid'] is somewhat arbitrary and could be any session variable you deem sufficient for the security of your application. Note: session variables are connected to the user and are saved from page to page until the session is destroyed by calling session_destroy().

If the above script is executed prior to every page load, then when some evil hacker tries to trigger the script without being logged in, they will be redirected to login.php before the rest of the script/page is executed/loaded.

Comment: Erm, no. The script will indeed **issue** a redirect to login.PHP before it executes the rest of the code, but in the absence of an exit statement after the call to header(), IT WILL STILL EXECUTE THE REST OF THE CODE.

Comment: Okay, you have two options for handling that: (as you mentioned) calling exit() or die() after the header redirect (presumably the rest of the could shouldn't be executed if that is reached), alternatively, you could put the rest of the code in an else statement. If there is some other issue, perhaps it would be helpful to provide a copy of the code in question.

Comment: Calling header() does not immediately redirect the user, it submits a header request with the processed page as it is sent. Also, it's important to note that if there is text preceding the call to header() it may prevent the header from being set

Comment: Would this still be the most viable method given the code I added to original post? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The current script is very insecure, but the insecurity **does not arise from the use of the md5** hash. It would be really difficult to bolt security on top a system like this using just Apache configuration.

You might want to start by reading up on [session security](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html) and [cross site request forgery.](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries)

You need to write some code. And since you've not posted any code nor proposed a specific solution, your question is rather off topic here.

Comment: Your analysis of how the script works is very wrong. You probably don't want to make any changes to this until you at least understand how it currently works and know a good deal more about secure programming.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys I feel moderately stupid now, but thank you for the tips on using the session handler as that is what ultimately pointed me in the correct direction and to look in the right place. After digging around it seems as though that particular admin file (account-ce.php), for whatever reason, was just missing this:

```
loggedinonly();
```

which is defined in backend/functions.php as:

```
function loggedinonly() {
    global $CURUSER;
    if (!$CURUSER) {
        header("Refresh: 0; url=account-login.php?returnto=" . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Also, I plan to read up on session security as you suggested so I can better familiarize myself with how sessions are used for this purpose. Thanks again! :)